How to set a max-width for a block with multiline text and have no extra space inside?
I'm kinda confused with a seemingly trivial issue with CSS.
I have a very simple HTML/CSS code (codepen):


.container {
  max-width: 230px;
  background: lightblue;
}
<div class="container">
  An priceless and thoughtful statement which contains exclusively elongated words.
</div>



The result of this code is the following:

However, I'd like to have a bit different result, when the div's width is no more than the max value set but also squeezed to its text content, like this:

How can I achive such a result?
Thank you.

P.S. I tried different approaches and with an extra display: inline; block (codepen) I can even see the target rectangle in the DevTools inspector, but still can't shrink the container to this rectangle.

